# Presign transaction to later publish with aave

Tags: aave

Is it possible to have pre-signed tx that I could publish to close a position with aave.
Let's imagine I have 0.1 wbtc deposited with aave and I borrow 1000 usdt. I can close my position from the webapp but is it possible that I presigned a 100usd to repay the usdt that I can publish later on?

Where should I start? Thanks